# setonclicklistener for a button in custom dialogfragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, dialogfragment

i have created a custom class extending dialog fragment and im using a layout to inflate into this dialog now when i want to set my onclicklistener in main activity but it returns null point exception when im setting my on click listener heres my main activity and my dialog fragment :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button cancelDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelDialogButton);
    View.OnClickListener listenerDialog = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };
//this is where i get the null point exception
    cancelDialog.setOnClickListener( listenerDialog );


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ViewGroup Addition = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_addition);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DialogCards editNameDialogFragment = DialogCards.newInstance();
                editNameDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");

        }
    });
```

and now my costume class extending dialog fragment :

```
public class DialogCards extends DialogFragment {


public Dialog dialog;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    // request a window without the title
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // Store access variables for window and blank point
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    Point size = new Point();
    // Store dimensions of the screen in `size`
    Display display = window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    // Set the width of the dialog proportional to 75% of the screen width
    window.setLayout((int) (size.x * 0.75), WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT + 20);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    // Call super onResume after sizing

    super.onResume();
}

public DialogCards() {

}

public static DialogCards newInstance() {
    DialogCards frag = new DialogCards();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.carddialog, container);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

}}
```

Comment: where exaclty are you getting null pointer? Can you please post your logs.

Comment: on the line that i set the in click listener to my button

Comment: do you have that button in main activity layout or in carddialog layout?

Comment: carddialog layout

Comment: If you have that button in carddialog layout you will not get that button in you mainactivity which is causing crash.  final Button cancelDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelDialogButton);
    View.OnClickListener listenerDialog = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }; Move this code to DialogFragment class

Comment: where exactly in the class can you post an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace this method in you DialogCards class

```
 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

  getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
  final Button cancelDialog = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.cancelDialogButton);
  View.OnClickListener listenerDialog = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
};
cancelDialog.setOnClickListener( listenerDialog );
}}
```